# More emphatic term for "Expert"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've hit a wording problem in the controls for a game that I'm writing.

I need two nouns with increasing emphasis for someone highly skilled in a given area.
"Expert" is an obvious choice, so I need a second noun which is:

- More emphatic than "Expert" - it must imply being extremely capable.
- Not gendered.  (This is why I've rejected the most obvious choice, "Master".)
- Obvious in its meaning, once read.
- Not too long - screen space is limited.
- Carrying connotations of *skill* but not necessarily *experience*.
- Applicable to many different areas of skill - professional skills (science, accounting) and personal (leadership, martial arts)

It is acceptable to use two words, so there could be a modifying adjective, but in that case space demands that they both be quite short.  ("Very skilled" would just work, but "World-famous expert" is out.)

(Edited to make criteria clearer)
If it matters, the setting is 60s to 80s Bond-movie-villain's lair.

Some characters are clones grown by a mad scientist and programmed for their tasks, so terms like "veteran" which imply experience as well as skill won't work.

Alternatively, I could use "Expert" in the top slot, to mean extreme skill... in which case I need a replacement word which is *less* emphatic than Expert, but carries the same connotations and matches the conditions above.  It will still need to mean "more than average skill" - the default is "professional competence", and the two terms I use need to describe two increasing levels above this.

Comment: What are the other levels of expertise you're using? (referring to your last paragraph).

Comment: @Neeku: At the moment "Expert" is the only word I've settled on; I only need two levels total.  Any character not described by one of the two terms I end up with has "standard professional competence, not worthy of comment".

Comment: Apologies for the digression but my personal take is that the term "master" is not as strongly gendered as you take it to be. There are often references to women who "master" something in the press.

Comment: Maven .....  :)?

Comment: To paraphrase a line I once read: "An _expert_ knows a great deal about a subject. A _scholar_ knows everything there is to know about a subject."

Comment: Personally I don't think "Master" would be taken to mean male only as it is usually used in an adjectival form when used in gaming terminology, and when "master" is used in an adjectival form, it's usually the noun it is attached to that determines the gender i.e. 'master blacksmith', 'master swordswoman', 'master chess player'.

Comment: @Pharap: As I've said in several other places, the adjectival form is neutral but here it will be used as a standalone noun, which most emphatically is *not*.

Comment: The way your question is/was worded implies/implied to me that these terms are used to indicate skill levels the player selects from a list in a manner akin to the typical 'hard, normal, easy' options found in most games (particularly 'I could use "Expert" in the top slot'). But as of your edit you are discussing the characters themselves, particularly the fact some are clones, which to me indicates that what you are actually after is names for character classes. What is going to be the exact use of these terms you seek? Is it difficulty level, class description or something else?

Comment: @Pharap: They are levels of skill which the character possesses.  Most skills in the game are "you have it or you don't" - "You have skills in Engineering, Finance, and Violence".  A character may, rarely, be exceptionally good - "You are an [Expert at Finance]" - and the wording of this is what I'm trying to pin down.  For design reasons I need to use the same terms across a broad range of abilities and characters.

Comment: @Tynam Thank you for clearing that up, that makes things a tad easier. Note that the word you choose will almost certainly have an impact on sentence structure and what strings you are able to form. (i.e. 'expert at finance', 'expert in finance', 'expert financier'). I would recommend you build a couple of test cases (or contexts) and plug-in the words suggested here to help narrow the field. A more variable term (like expert, as demonstrated above) can open up flexibility within the script, which is always a desirable feature within the world of game design.

Comment: How about Artisan? It emphasizes skill without stating expertise. Or maybe a "Supreme [character class]"

ar·ti·san
noun
1. a person skilled in an applied art; a craftsperson.

Comment: @Pharap: That's exactly this issue that's making me so picky with the answers ;) - I need it to be a single word on screen, but flexible to use meaningfully in context in the full briefings.

Comment: @Tynam I'm a programmer with experience in parsing and game design so I understand your predicament. Like I say, write some sample script and try plugging different terms in and in as many ways as possible. If none of the suggestions here are fitting I would recommend first rewording the question again with more details and context. I understand that you probably want to keep details of your game under wraps, but sometimes showing your cards is the best way forward. Failing that you may have to consider your design in need of reworking and see if you can find a way to improve flexibility.

Comment: **Is this for descriptions of characters on a game**?  if so - why didn't you say so?

Comment: "Baller": Someone that may be "Ballin out of control"

Comment: "master" or "grandmaster" doesn't seem gendered to me. What do you think? I don't think I see the word "grandmistress" that often. It's even marked as error in my Mac. Although I think it's a bit too specific to chess.

Comment: If you need an adjective, "eminent" could be of use.

Comment: Connoisseur comes to mind

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Dreyfus model of skill acquisition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyfus_model_of_skill_acquisition)? In particular, his ranking is:

1. Novice
2. Advanced beginner
3. Competent
4. Proficient
5. Expert

Note that each level has a specific, quotable, empirically-driven definition that allows one to (more-or-less) unambiguously identify which category one belongs to.

That might be helpful if your application is a self-survey which is otherwise vulnerable to differences of interpretation: a standard model has the benefit of normalization (to a larger extent than, say, “on a scale of one to ten. . . .”).

That said, since perfect standardization is an impossible ideal, if you implement this, you might consider offering an "other" option.

Alternatively, the word *specialist* comes to mind.

Comment: No self-survey needed; this is a game, and characters are rated by the game rules.  I just need terms to rate them *as*.  +1, because "specialist" is a great suggestion.

Comment: +1. Competent, proficient and specialist are would all help offer additional gradations to the scale, although most of them would fall below expert (with the arguable exception of "specialist").

Comment: @ChrisSunami I think you're right, but "specialist" is (as you mentioned) arguable, because it feels like it should be used in _just one area_, as opposed to the other words which are read in a wider, more general way.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, even though I didn't use it in practice, because it's the best general suggestion for the question as written - we didn't use it only due to other factors.

Answer (score 29):

The most obvious short word I can think of that could be seen as being a level ‘above’ *expert* would be [***guru***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guru), in the third sense given by Merriam-Webster in the link:

> a person who has a lot of experience in or knowledge about a particular subject

Comment: Ooh, interesting suggestion which I hadn't considered.  I'll try wording some of the rules briefings this way and see how it reads.

Comment: A lot of negative connotation around the word guru in my experience. I've only heard it used sarcastically to describe someone who is wiggling their way into a position they do not have the expertise to fill.

Comment: @ClassicThunder That is quite the opposite of my experience of the word. I have never heard any such connotation implied—rather, the word almost has connotations of _reverence_ in my experience.

Comment: It also has connotations bleeding over from the first two senses.

Comment: @Vadim Certainly—but those are positive connotations (and the reverence bit probably comes from the first sense), not negative ones. :-)

Comment: @ClassicThunder: A lot of words take on both positive and negative connotations. Pretty much **any** ostensibly positive word can take on a negative meaning simply by saying it with enough of a sneer. The very fact that it *can* be used sarcastically derives from its nonsarcastic (more intrinsic) meaning.

Comment: GURU is used positively in the IT world, even in the occasional job description.

Comment: Nah, in programming a guru is just "an incredibly good programmer," particularly with sysadmin skills.  You would never describe an **industry figure,** a **captain of industry** type (say, Steve Jobs) as a mere guru.

Comment: When we wrote it up guru carried slightly more connotation of "teacher" or "example" than we wanted, so I'm accepting elsewhere.  This is a good answer though.  +1.

Answer (score 12):

Depending on what kind of flavor you’re going for, I have several possibilities that haven't yet been suggested.

First, as others have said, for me *master* doesn’t have the gendered feel to it that you describe.  But given this opinion, there are of course other options.

For a term that could be used to describe someone more skilled than *expert* denotes, there’s *virtuoso* and also *maven* (although the latter may not have the right feel; I’d be unlikely to use it myself, to be honest).

If you’re looking for a word below *expert*, you could use *adept* to describe their skill level. As in a person is either average, an adept, or an expert.

Alternatively, *skilled*, *accomplished*, *talented*, *proficient*, or *gifted*.

Comment: +1 for Virtuoso. I agree that Maven is a bit too unknown, though I have seen it used once in a console game so it certainly has its place.

Comment: Virtuoso is more appropriate than the higher-voted answers

Comment: I like Expert and Adept.

Comment: If I were designing the game as the OP described, I'd probably go for Competent -> Adept -> Expert

Answer (score 11):

If the level being described is the ultimate attainable, perhaps the term **[paragon](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/paragon)** might suit

> A person or thing regarded as a perfect example of a particular quality [ODO]

Similarly, you might consider *apotheosis* (although less often applied to an individual than to her accomplishments), *paradigm*, or *epitome*.

Comment: Blast.  Paragon is perfect... except that I neglected to mention that most characters are *extremely evil*.  Paragon carries a connotation of moral as well as professional excellence, so I'll have to let it go.

Comment: There are a not-insignificant number of instances of [*paragon of evil*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22paragon%20of%20evil%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1992,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) in literature.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps [*savant*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/savant?q=savant):

> a learned person, especially a distinguished scientist.

In my experience, this word has connotations of almost supernatural expertise.

Comment: Are you citing from somewhere, or is that your own definition?

Answer (score 7):

You can use *ace*. It’s even shorter than *guru*.

Comment: The slight difference in connotation between the two is that *Guru* tends to be also a wise teacher, while *Ace* may be a loner, not willing to share the gift.

Comment: Yes. That's why I'm not recommending *jedi*

Comment: Ace also has connotations of showing off.

Comment: The showing-off/loner connotations aren't major issues, so I'm considering this if something more neutral isn't suggested.

Answer (score 5):

A *[prodigy](http://thesaurus.com/browse/prodigy)* is a person of extraordinary talent.

Update

As a second word (noting that you are looking for two words), less "emphatic" than *prodigy* might be *[gifted](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gifted)*.

> having exceptionally high intelligence;  revealing special talent

In my experience, *gifted* would be one rung lower than *prodigy*. A gifted individual is one who shows great potential for exceptional talent, whereas a prodigy actually possesses extraordinary talent.

Comment: Aha!  This does the job perfectly.  Better than expert, no extra connotations, short, and applies to a wide range of skills and fields.  Writing this in to the game now; I'll accept this answer there isn't a *more* perfect one by the time I go live.

Comment: Prodigy also carries strong connotations of youth.  Young + talented = prodigy.  You might not want the "young" part for your game.

Comment: @James: Most characters in the game are brain-programmed clones... so they're *less than two weeks old*.  I can live with "youth".  There's only one expert character who's older than two weeks... and she's the ingenue.

Comment: This may well be the best answer for OP's specific use, but it's clearly not the best answer for the question as written.

Comment: @John Y: True.  I walked an awkward line between adding enough detail to answer the question and digressing into massive explanation of the game; apparently I fell just shy of my target.

Comment: In the end we did use "prodigy" in several places in the game rules, but I'm moving over to "specialist" in the long term, so I've accepted the answer above.  +1 to you.

Answer (score 4):

An *authority*; or, if you want to approach, but perhaps not cross, the *guru* line, an *adept* might do.

Comment: Well answered! Perhaps you could [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/186480/edit) your answer to insert a definition of _adept_, and a reference (link or otherwise) to where you found the definition? That would improve the answer a lot.

Comment: **authority** is a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

One could use the word *adept*.

One definition supplied by [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adept#Noun) is:

> Well skilled; completely versed; thoroughly proficient

Comment: A little bit of corroboration via a dictionary would be nice. *Adept* (particularly when used as a noun, and particularly when meaning "the highest level of expertise") has a strong connotation of the occult, which may not always be desirable.

Comment: Adept is also used in myriad games as an intermediate level.

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider using the old trade guild hierarchy of:

- Apprentice
- Journeyman
- Master

Comment: I'd thought of this, but it has the problem that comes from being old - it's far too strongly gendered.  I won't room for context, and by themselves "Journeyman" and "Master" are both far too male.

Comment: @Tynam - Fair enough. I'd argue neither is really considered particularly gendered these days when used as a adjective, but they do both have that history.

Comment: As an adjective they're not very gendered, but my question calls for a noun... which definitely is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to suggest ***doyen***. If you are a doyen, you are not only the most expert in that subject but also the most respected and the one who has been there the longest. Doyen would be the most knowledgeable in a group of experts also. So, it is obviously the ultimate level in a real world.

In the current vernacular, *doyen* is used as a gender-neutral word but there is also the feminine version *doyenne*.

There are also ***connoisseur*** and ***cognoscente*** (or cognoscenti) but they are usually used for people who has superior knowledge in fine arts and literature, and they are the authority in the field.

Comment: I think doyen falls prey to the gender issue, wikipedia lists its meaning as 'The senior, or eldest male member of a group.' (its other definitions are noted as colloquial and obsolete, so I am disregarding them).

Comment: @Pharap: There are contemporary usages that is used for both genders.

Answer (score 2):

In a well-known rock opera, Tommy was a pinball *wizard*. I feel that he would beat a mere pinball *guru*.

Then I searched for “wizard level of expertise” since I should show some sort of source here, and found [some evidence at a site named Wizards of Gyan](http://www.wizardsofgyan.com/about-us/the-evolution-of-a-wizard) that apparently software people use sentences like

> To build awesome software, we need awesome people (our wizards).

and

> We think each of these competency areas have 5 stages of expertise. These
>       stages are awareness, discerning, mastering, coaching and wizardry.

But then they would, or they wouldn't have called themselves wizardsofgyan.com.

Anyway, in software development I think this is the right answer. I don’t know if other sectors regularly use *wizard* in this way, but for a computer game it should be fine.

Comment: A concern for the use of *wizard* to me is that the game might have a wizard class which could cause confusion.  Even if it **didn't**, wizards are common enough in games that the term could still cause confusion.

Comment: I thought of this too, but given that this is for a game, I think the definition as "magic user" would overshadow the intended meaning.

Comment: As of the update to the question it is apparent that the term wizard would be unlikely clash with anything in game. However it doesn't quite fit the theme.

Comment: Also, A funny Pepsi commercial always helps improve a source's validity.

Answer (score 1):

When talking strictly about knowledge rather than practical skill, *authority* would seem the right term, because it implies that the person’s level of expertise is not only very high but also widely recognised as such.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [*veteran*](https://www.google.com/#q=define:+veteran) as well. From Google:

> a person who has had long experience in a particular field.

Other sources:

- [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/veteran?s=t)
- [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/veteran)
- [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/veteran?q=veteran)

I'm not sure if I'd consider that below or above *expert*, though.

Comment: I’m sorry, but “from Google” is **not** a valid reference.  Please see [these guidelines](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981/2085) on how to properly cite something.

Comment: Fair enough. Here is my Google source as well as three reputable dictionaries that agree with my definition. [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=define:+veteran), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/veteran?s=t), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/veteran), [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/veteran?q=veteran).

Regardless, is a downvote really the right way to go? The word I suggested is a valid suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The word **sensei** popped into my head when I read this as did guru.  While the literal translation of sensei means "born before", the cultural connotations for my martial arts friends is their senseis were a master or teacher for their chosen art, which seems to work for your game.

However, reading up on it a bit more, the term "[**dai-sensei**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensei#Etymology)" came up which refers to the top sensei in a given system.  Perhaps that may work?

Comment: You don't have to couch this by saying it has "cultural connotations". For all intents and purposes, this is simply the Japanese word for *master*, and by now I think it's well-enough understood in English, so it does serve as an answer to the question.

Comment: If you're going to bring in 'Sensei', I recommend you also mention 'Senpai'. It may not be as well known, but it is highly applicable nonetheless http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senpai.

Comment: After reading your link, I think 'senpai' may be an appropriate word for someone of higher rank (than their kōhai) who assists the sensei (who's a higher rank yet).  Were you suggesting it as the upper ranking individual the OP asked for?

Comment: @tchrist I wasn't aware there were rules regarding style on Stack Exchange?  If there are, a cursory look didn't reveal them.  I make no claims regarding my typography or scholarly abilities.  If you don't like my style or resultant typography please feel free to down vote rather than edit or comment.  

I see that at least one person has.  

If there are rules that I've bent or broken, please point them out to me, otherwise, please go moderate someone else's posts.

Comment: From total ignorance: is *sensei* gendered in Japanese?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has yet offered it, I will throw ***genius*** into the ring:

Variously:

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genius):

> : a very smart or talented person : a person who has a level of talent or intelligence that is very rare or remarkable

From [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/genius):

> 1b. A person of extraordinary intellect and talent (American Heritage Dictionary)
> 1. a person with exceptional ability, esp of a highly original kind (Collins)
> 1. an exceptional natural capacity of intellect, esp. as shown in creative and original work in science, art, music, etc.: the genius of Mozart.
> 2. a person having such capacity. (Random House)

Words that keep coming up in definitions and descriptions of *genius* include *extraordinary*, *exceptional*, *transcendent*, *remarkable*, and *rare*. I'd say this fits the bill nicely. It doesn't imply a gender or an age (though it's usually clear pretty early when someone's a genius), and it implies something very special and innate that is more than just what can be gained from experience.

Answer (score 1):

**whiz(z)**

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whiz):

> (*informal*) Someone who is remarkably skilled at something.

[Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whizz):

> *Informal*. a person who is quite good at a particular activity, in a certain field, etc.: *She's a whiz at math.*

**dab hand**

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dab_hand):

> (*UK*) An expert; a very skilled person.

[Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dab+hand):

> 1. a person skilled in something; an expert.
> 2. an excellent or extraordinary person or thing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **Specialist**?

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specialist

spe·cial·ist noun \ˈspe-sh(ə-)list\
: a person who has special knowledge and skill relating to a particular job, area of study, etc.

: a doctor who deals with health problems that relate to a specific area of medicine

: a rank in the U.S. Army that is above the rank of private and below the rank of corporal

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

As it appears what you are asking for is a way to classify the clones, I would suggest terms more akin to:

- **Professional** - "A person who earns his living from a specified activity"
- **Apprentice** - "A trainee, especially in a skilled trade"
- **Peon** - "A lowly person, a peasant or serf, a labourer who is obliged to do menial work"
- **Serf** - "(strategy games) A worker unit"

---

Lower skill level:

- **Rookie** - "A novice."
- **Newcomer** - "One who has recently come to a community; a recent arrival." (A nice way of saying 'noob').
- **Novice** - "A beginner; one who is not very familiar or experienced in a particular subject."

Higher skill level:

- **Veteran** - "A person with long experience of a particular activity"

All definitions taken from wiktionary.

Comment: All good answers to the question I wrote... which unfortunately prove that I didn't write it well enough.  Editing and adding explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your edit.  I'm not trying to classify the clones so much as their skill levels, in a way that I can also use for the non-clone characters.  Anybody less skilled than "professional" simply doesn't have the skill at all, so I only need terms for those who are better than mere professional competence.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for

**leading expert,**

**authority,** (vote up Jebediah, above)

or

**industry figure.**

Note that "world-famous expert" or perhaps "world-renowned expert" are also good, but perhaps a bit stagey.

Answer (score 0):

A top-ranked opponent can be called [*champion*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/champion), which carries both the notion of a combatant for a cause and of undefeated.  It also combines with a second word (for example, *world champion*) in case you wanted to draw finer distinctions.

Answer (score 0):

**Divinity** has been used in the context of games (for a leader rather than an expert). You may also choose a particular name depending on the type of game you're developing, if it is rather on fine skill an **artist** or **maestro** may be appropriate, although maestro is originally gendered.

Answer (score 0):

### Perhaps [*Adroit*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adroit)

> 1. expert or nimble in the use of the hands or body.
> 2. cleverly skillful, resourceful, or ingenious: an adroit debater.

While the first definition implies physical skill, the second shows that it is also used of other types of skill. It does not have any connotation of experience, but purely to skill itself used in a way better than most. The word could probably be used as either a level above or below *expert*, depending upon how you wanted to spin it.

Of course, for your game purposes, if this term were used you would effectively be making this adjective into a noun by such a use (you stated you were seeking a noun in your question). They would be termed "adroits" or individually, "an adroit," but the context could probably pull off the [substantive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/substantive?s=t) use of the adjective for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I quite like the term [*Arbiter*](http://gog.is/define+arbiter) for describing someone at the absolute top of the chain of command.

Particularly the description **`ultimate authority in a matter`**.

It may not work for everything, but it's another interesting option.