# A laudatory expression for “an expert in grammar”

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, compliment

All too often, the 19th century scholars who wrote volumes on English grammar are today accused of being pedantic; persnickety; puritanical and  prescriptivist poppycock grammarians.

In the 21st century the  epithets *grammar Nazi* and *grammar police* are launched at anyone brave (or foolish) enough to point out that the word *photo's* does not require an apostrophe, or that *noone* should be written as two words "no one". Which aren't even grammar corrections but spelling ones. Anyway...

What do call a person who is an expert on the English language and its grammar? A person who always provides a clear answer to any language problem, a person who is infinitely helpful, modest and kind.  Do we only call them an "expert" on grammar?

Is there a ***laudatory*** expression that we can use?

Here are just two I found on EL&U, the third was coined by me, but I'm sure there are many others.

- crazy grammar genius
- punctuation czar
- grammar queen

**N.B**
EL&U rightly frowns on long lists, so no more than three suggestions please.

Comment: Grammar guru. Honestly, though, if you're unsolicitedly correcting someone's grammar, you're going to get negativity thrown at you. Pedant.

Comment: The real experts share the low opinion of prescriptivists as grammar nazis who are ignorant dilettantes.

Comment: _Programmarian_ ?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I like *grammar guru* I should've thought of it myself. Oh dear... Greg Lee who are these "real experts", the descriptivists? Is the latter considered a compliment?

Comment: Not very helpful, I'm afraid, but I would call these people (and there are some wonderful people on this site) *invaluable resources*, *great teachers*, language role models, etc. Sorry, can't think of anything better. Grammar guru sounds quite nice.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, well, I'm an expert.  Yes, descriptivists, in general.  I consider "descriptivist" as complimentary.

Comment: I'm an expert at the same level as Greg (emeritus), but I don't like the term _descriptivist_;  it implies there's another real variety of grammar. That's about as true as the idea that there is evolutionary biology and there is creationist biology, and they're on the same level, both biology. So called "prescriptivists" are naive social engineers, not grammarians. As Greg said, they're ignorant dilettantes.

Comment: Re your recent edit and the irony, I actually thought that was intentional from the beginning. It wasn't? Nor the "A person who ...provide(s?)" in the next sentence?

Comment: @PapaPoule No, it wasn't, (I almost wish it was) but it's a common spelling mistake of mine, fossilized. Oh dear, another typo. You're right about "provides". How did I miss that one?! In conclusion I am neither a *spelling guru*, nor a *grammar maven*.

Comment: Frankly I'm glad you're not because, taking the adjectives from your question, their helpfulness is too often overshadowed by their lack of modesty and kindness and in those cases the pejoratives you mention, and worse, are certainly well deserved.

Comment: It looks like "ignorant dilettante" is about the best you're going to get.

Comment: @HotLicks ta very much. Charming! ;)

Comment: English teacher? Perhaps Librarian?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Y'know, the more I think about it, the more I think there simply **isn't** any laudatory term in English for a grammarian, whether genuine or feigned, wise or ignorant. Grammar just is not something one lauds. This says a lot more about the attitude of English speakers than it does about anything else.

Comment: "It is the fate of those who toil at the lower employments of life…
to be exposed to censure without hope of praise…
Among these unhappy mortals is the writer of dictionaries…
Every other author may aspire to praise;
the lexicographer can only hope to escape reproach."

—Samuel Johnson (Dictionary of the English language, 1755)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A term that has laudatory connotations is **language maven**. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maven) defines *maven* as follows:

> A *maven* (also *mavin*) is a trusted expert in a particular field, who
>   seeks to pass knowledge on to others. The word *maven* comes from
>   Hebrew, meaning "*one who understands*", based on an accumulation of
>   knowledge.

As Wikipedia further notes:

> Since the 1980s it (*maven*) has become more common since William Safire
>   adopted it to describe himself as "*the language maven*". The word is
>   mainly confined to American English, but did not appear with the
>   publication of the 1976 edition of Webster's Third New International
>   Dictionary; it is, however, included in the Oxford English Dictionary
>   second edition (1989) and the American Heritage Dictionary fourth
>   edition (2000). Numerous individuals and entities now affix *maven* or
>   *mavin* to assert their expertise in a particular area.

The following is an extract from The New York Times, the newspaper in which Safire wrote a regular column about language issues (called *On Language*) until his death in 2009:

> Though he jokingly anointed himself “*Usage Dictator*,” he was never
>   comfortable with expectations that he play the part of language
>   absolutist, handing down infallible decrees. “*Maven*” was a title more
>   to his liking, a Yiddishism that he said contained its own “*note of
>   self-mockery*.” (An incurable paronomasiac, he also enjoyed punning off
>   the word, as in his 1993 collection of columns, “*Quoth the Maven*.”)

And further:

> As battles raged between prescriptive grammarians and descriptive
>   linguists and lexicographers, Safire more often than not played both
>   sides against the middle.

Note: The *[On Language](http://topics.nytimes.com/top/features/magazine/columns/on_language/index.html)* articles in The New York Times were continued for a while by maven Ben Zimmer, who is also a regular contributor to [Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/).

Comment: The problem with _maven_ is (a) it's Yiddish; (b) it's in casual use in New York city; (c) it's been applied to William Safire, who was an entertaining writer, but who knew nothing about English grammar -- probably because he wrote for the _New York Times_, which views New York as the cultural center of the nation.

Comment: William Safire is the only popular language commentator I ever read a book by.  And I did that because my mother bought me his **On Language** book -- a collection of his newspaper columns. (She thought that's the kind of thing I did.  I had to read it.)  It wasn't bad.  He was fact-oriented, a good observer, and had lots of interesting anecdotes.  He had made an effort to learn some descriptive linguistics.  I read it all the way through, as I was pleased to be able to report to my mother.

Comment: @JohnLawler. That Safire knew nothing about English grammar is debatable. This is what Professor Pullum says in a comment on Ben Zimmer's obituary (http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1774) to Safire on Language Log: "_We should not forget that Safire formed a lasting pen-pal relationship with the great MIT-trained linguist and polymath James D. McCawley, and consulted McCawley regularly, and clearly valued what he learned thereby. Another sign of his intellectual openness and genuine interest._"

Comment: "Quoth the maven, 'Never bore!' "

Comment: Yes, he wasn't as bad as some of the other English language shamans that Bolinger talked about. BTW, given the OQ, some consideration should be given to ***Shaman*** (pronounced /'ʃeimən/ in academic English). English Language shamans are self-appointed authorities about correct usage, usually writers or talking heads who fancy they understand things and wish to enlighten the masses. Read Bolinger's great _Language: The Loaded Weapon_ to see the picture.

Answer (score 2):

*Professional linguist* would be an accurate term for such a person, though it's not an all-encompassing one (because there are many 'grammar gurus' who do not make a living from their language expertise). We also have the terms *English teacher* and *English professor* for people who are (in principle) expert in English and disseminate their knowledge to others.

Terms like *grammar Nazi* and *grammar police* exist in response to the fact that:

1. not everyone welcomes having their linguistic practices commented on or 'corrected';
2. many self-styled experts cannot tell the difference between their own personal preferences and usages they are merely unfamiliar with, but apply their own prejudices regardless; and
3. some of them have a habit of claiming greater knowledge or expertise than they actually possess.

Incidentally, it is unlikely that I would describe myself as a *grammar queen* even if I possessed the necessary level of expertise to qualify for the title.

Regarding the term *grammar guru,* I have the following observations:

1. 'Grammar guru' does not occur in the OED as an established term.
2. The citations contained in the OED's [entry for *guru*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82664?redirectedFrom=guru#eid) (of which a clone can be found [here](http://findwords.info/term/guru)) refer solely to the term's religious usage until 1957, after which it occurs in a secular context, sometimes as a less-than-complimentary term.

(For instance, an article in the London *Times* dated 4 October 1968 reports the British Prime Minister Harold Wilson talking about Enoch Powell, the Conservative MP for Wolverhampton:

> "In what was obviously intended to be a sneering reference, the Prime Minister in his facile glibness..described Mr. Enoch Powell as ‘the **guru** of Wolverhampton’."

Here, Wilson was using 'guru' as a snarky epithet for a political opponent whom he regarded as a false prophet and troublemaker — in April 1968, Powell had delivered his notorious 'Rivers of Blood' speech opposing new legislation that would make it easier for immigrants from the Commonwealth to settle in Britain.)

My attempts to pin down the earliest attested occurrence of *grammar guru* have been largely fruitless.

The term is not found either in Brigham Young University's Corpus of Contemporary American English [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), its Corpus of Historical American English [(COHA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/), its [Strathy Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/can/) (of Canadian English), or its British National Corpus [(BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/); nor in Oxford University's [BNC](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/). I have searched other corpora too, but with the exception of BYU's Corpus of Global Web-Based English [(GloWbE)](https://www.english-corpora.org/glowbe/), which contained only a handful of what appeared to be relatively recent hits, these too were devoid of the term.

For what it's worth, the domain name *grammarguru.com* was (according to [Whois.net](https://www.whois.net/)) first registered in 1999.

The nearest I could come is a 1997 reference to [*slang guru*](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=15497) by Jonathon Green, the renowned lexicographer of English slang, describing Eric Partridge (the author of *inter alia* A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English).

Comment: I mentioned *grammar Nazi* and *grammar police* in my post because (1) I didn't want anyone to post them as answers (2) to illustrate that casual *pejorative* terms existed. I would like a casual laudatory expression.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes, I get all those things. I'm not sure there are many more laudatory expressions for this concept, but we'll have to see what else other people come up with.

Comment: A very good answer. Thank you! It's curious how the tag *guru* appears to be both pejorative and laudatory.

Comment: @Mari-Lou There's a bit of comment-talk about the dual connotation of _guru_ on [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186366/more-emphatic-term-for-expert/186371#186371), though I have to say I've still never come across negative uses in real life—only here on ELU.

Comment: Professional linguists these days tend to be far on the descriptivist side of the descriptivism-prescriptivism spectrum, while the kind of person that is described in the question seems to be at least somewhat on the prescriptivist side.

Answer (score 1):

Grammarian, perhaps? I appreciate a great editor, however, being an expert in grammar and knowing the applicable style guide are just prerequisites for being a great editor.

Comment: The term *grammarian* describes someone who studies and writes about grammar. It is in the question I posted. I would like a more informal casual word/expression that describes such an expert.

Comment: Apologies. The downvote was from me. It was entirely unintended and must have happened during ham-fisted scrolling of the page. I searched on Meta but apparently the downvote is irrevocable and a compensatory upvote is only possible after the post has been edited.

Comment: @Shoe You should be able to un-downvote by just clicking the downvote triangle again.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Within 5 minutes of the original downvote.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. Unfortunately, I didn't discover the error until an hour or so later. Maybe we should have an "_Are you sure_?" alert before committing to the downvote. Anyway, I 've learned to be more attentive in future.

Comment: @Shoe if it bothers you so much, edit the answer—just adding an extra space is suffice, and you can undo your vote.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***Grammar wiz*** may be a satisfactory answer. *'Wiz' means a person who is extremely clever at something,* so to refer to a person who provides any clear answer to any linguistic or grammatical problem we may use the coinage '***Grammar wiz***'.
2. ***Punctuation pundit*** cab be used to refer to person who is an authority in grammar (*pundit* means the same thing as *guru*). This coinage is alliterative so quite pleasing to the ears.

Comment: Unfortunately, punctuation isn't part of grammar. And _wiz_ is short for _wizard_, which is much more laudatory than _wiz_.

Answer (score 0):

**Human**

Unless they suffer from a birth defect or suffer some sort of injury to the language centers, humans have an innate ability to construct and parse human languages.  A child of 6 has command of most language features -- he just lacks vocabulary.

A "grammarian" knows the *names* of the various parts of speech, and can spout a bunch of supposed "rules" about language construction, but arguably his comprehension of the *real* rules is only marginally better than the child's.  In fact, the grammarian may have, as a result of attempting to reduce the rules etched in the brain to a set of marks on paper, lost some knowledge of the *real* language that the 6-year-old still possesses.

Comment: An expert in grammar is not necessarily a grammarian by profession. He or she may have a passion for the language and have a knack for understanding its complexities and nuances. There are such people, and yes, they too are human. :)

Answer (score -1):

Why not create a new word or descriptive term.
How about “grammarsmith” since “wordsmith” has already been coined?